# haskell program to remove part of list and print the rest

Tags: haskell

How do I remove a part of a list in Haskell? This is what I have done so far. Please tell me what are the changes that can be made:

```
import Data.List
import Data.List.Split

removePrefix :: Eq t => [t] -> [t] -> Maybe [t]
removePrefix [] [] = Nothing
removePrefix ts [] = Just ts 
removePrefix (t:ts) (y:ys) = 
  if inTnFixOf (y:ys) (t:ts) == True
  then SrtipPrefix (y:ys) (t:ts)
  else Just [(x:xs)]
```

Example: input "toyboat" output "boat"

Comment: Can you please edit your code, so that it compiles? Some typos and indentation errors.

Comment: i'm rather green to haskell, don't quite know how to handle these errors. So, any help would suffice.

Comment: It would help if you could post those errors

Comment: Could not find module `Data.List.Split'

Comment: try: `cabal install split` in your terminal; do you want to remove all sublists from a list or only prefixes?

Comment: should i download the addon or can i just type it??

Comment: Requested packages are already installed.

Answer (score 2):

Already exists function `stripPrefix` from `Data.List`

```
 stripPrefix "foo" "foobar" == Just "bar"
 stripPrefix "foo" "foo" == Just ""
 stripPrefix "foo" "barfoo" == Nothing
 stripPrefix "foo" "barfoobaz" == Nothing
```

is defined as

```
stripPrefix :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
stripPrefix [] ys = Just ys
stripPrefix (x:xs) (y:ys)
 | x == y = stripPrefix xs ys
stripPrefix _ _ = Nothing
```

So, you could just declare:

```
removePrefix [] [] = Nothing
removePrefix xs ys = stripPrefix xs ys
```

Answer (score 1):

the following removes all sublists from a given list:

```
import Data.List.Split

rmSublist :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
rmSublist [] _ = []
rmSublist _ [] = []
rmSublist xs ys = concat $ filter (/=[]) (splitOn xs ys)
```

alternatively, if you want to remove only the prefix:

```
rmPrefix :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
rmPrefix [] ys = ys
rmPrefix _ [] = []
rmPrefix xs ys =
  if xs == take n ys
  then drop n ys
  else ys
  where n = length xs
```